# Laravel Eloquent - how to relate table to another by two fields

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Having two tables `User` and `Mail`

`MailTable`:

```
\mail
\--|id
\--|user_id
\--|from_user_id
\--|other_fields
```

`UserTable`:

```
\user
\--|id
\--|name
\--|other_fields
```

the `Mail` table is related to user by two fields => `user_id` and `from_user_id`, how to use eloquent to fetch data related to user to get **inbox** and **outbox(sent)** for one user?

Comment: Please paste your models, current mapping. A hasOne in User relationship should work with belongsTo from Mail

Comment: You can use eloquent using one to many, for more details please check this -  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how your models have been defined, but something like this should work.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Mail extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }

    public function from_user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'from_user_id');
    }
}
```

Then to fetch, use: `$from_user = $mail->from_user`

Adjust the namespaces according to how they've been defined in your application.

Comment: I was also thinking the same solution at least you made me sure. +1